# Dynamic access to the object name

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to select certain property of dynamic object

```
var minus = {
    doAction: function(){
        console.log("this is minus");
    }
}

var plus = {
    doAction: function(){
        console.log("this is plus");
    }
}

var panelEvents = {
    button: function(){
        $(document).on("click", ".plus, .minus", function(){
            var buttonClass = $(this).attr('class');
        window[buttonClass][doAction](); //get an error
        });
    }
}

panelEvents.button();
```

Questions
1. How can I dynamically call various objects with the same methods?
2. Is it bad practice in point of OOP view to access methods in such way?

**UPDATE**

I understood, that it is not flexible approach. So now I have only theoretical interest of accessing dynamic object. Neither

```
window[buttonClass]['doAction']();
```

nor

```
window[buttonClass].doAction();
```

working.
Firebug:
TypeError: window[buttonClass] is undefined
window[buttonClass]'doAction';

Should I obviously attach minus and plus objects to window?

**SOLUTION**
The problem was that my code was inside jQuery object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//my code
)};
```

Comment: `window[buttonClass].doAction()`

Comment: I would not rely on class name to get the name of variable/property. If you need to change class name, you'd need to re-factor entire code and on the contrary. I'd rather have on input manager that would be holding hashmap that maps buttons with objects I want to interact with in my application layer. If you want to stick with your current implementation, @elclanrs gave you solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line that fails, you are trying to call a function that is named the same as the content of the variable doAction. The problem here is that doAction is not defined.

You would have to write:

```
window[buttonClass]['doAction']();
```

or

```
window[buttonClass].doAction();
```

Comment: Console returns me an error anyway.
Firebug:
TypeError: window[buttonClass] is undefined
window[buttonClass]['doAction']();
Opera:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'doAction' of undefined

Comment: I find the problem was that my code was inside jQuery object. $(document).ready(function(){ ... });